# Rendering an HTML file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using CarrierWave to upload static HTML templates to certain user profiles on my webpage.

I am trying to render the HTML file on the user's home page once they log in. The Path for the HTML file after uploading is:

/uploads/profile/curation/8/User_Content.html

I'm new to rails and I thought I'd just be able to

```
<%= render /uploads/profile/curation/8/User_Content.html %>
```

to get the html to render, but I guess that only works for partials, which this is not.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `render_to_string`. Please have a look over here. http://russbrooks.com/2009/11/18/embed-a-static-hmtl-page-in-a-rails-view

Comment: hmm ok so in my profiles controller I added 

"@myhtml = render_to_string :file => @profile.curation.to_s"

then in my show.html.erb view I added 

"<%= @myhtml %>"

But still nothing is showing...is there something else I need to do to render it properly? Also those statements are not strings...I just had to type quotes around them so I could post the comment :P

Comment: Actually sorry I was dumb and had it in the wrong controller...

The error is actually occurring at  "@myhtml = render_to_string :file => @profile.curation.to_s"   Which says that there is a missing template for the file.  Any idea?

Comment: if i navigate to localhost:3000/uploads/profile/curation/8/User_Content.html I am able to see the HTML that I uploaded...Idk if that information will help at all, but I hope it does.

Comment: try this `render_to_string(:file => "/uploads/profile/curation/8/User_Content.html", :layout => nil).html_safe`

Answer (score -1):

In your controller you can redirect to the page you want:

```
redirect_to "/uploads/profile/curation/8/User_Content.html"
```

Comment: is it possible to just get that uploaded html, and render it on the page I am currently on? 

Like on profiles/8

Comment: If you read it into a string (`@myhtml = File.open('full_path_to_file')`) in the controller you can output it n the view using `<%= raw @myhtml %>`.  The `raw` is required so that the markup isn't sanitized.  Make sure you trust the HTML you're displaying!

Comment: Good idea! I did the following (the html is stored under the collumn name "curation")

<% @myhtml = File.open(@profile.curation.to_s) %>

but it says that the file does not exist... I checked in my rails app folder, which is "/public/uploads/profile/curation/8/User_Content.html" and it does seem to be there.

Do I need to include the "public" before it?

Comment: Ok so one more update, I got the file.open to not give me an error, however it is returning me the memory location of the file instead of the content of the file itself 

Output is something like <file 0x53429as></file 0x53429as>

Advice?

Comment: You need to load the file in the controller, not the view. Read up on File.open's syntax. It's hard to be concise in the comments.